# Dynamic change the column name of file from aws s3 bucket

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, amazon-s3, arr

I have to change the column name of CSV file that file will be stored on AWS s3 bucket , dynamically I want to change the column name and should be updated on AWS also.
example the payload would be

```
{
    "file_url": "https://myfile.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/student.csv",
    "column": "name",
    "update_col_name":'full_name'
}
```

example of originol json file:

```
[{name:'Aditya',age:'24'},{name:'Kumar',age:'14'}]
```

after updation the file would be

```
[{full_name:'Aditya',age:'24'},{full_name:'Kumar',age:'14'}]
```

using Nodejs is this possible

Comment: can you show the code which you have already tried?

Comment: previously I have tried and I am able to give the response to user  for local temp file

Comment: var stream = s3.getObject(params).createReadStream();
        var jsons = await csv().fromStream(stream);
        var data = []
        var flag = false;
        //console.log(jsons[0])
        if (jsons[0][col_name]) {
          flag = true
        }
        if (flag === true) {
          jsons.forEach(element => {
            for (let key in element) {
              if (key === col_name) {
                data.push({ date: element[Object.keys(element)[0]], [key]: element[key] })
        }
            }
          })
          res.json({ data })
        }

Comment: You can add the code in your question by editing  it

Comment: Your question mentions CSV file, but your samples are JSON. Is there a reason you mentioned CSV?

Comment: from aws s3 bucket I am fetching csv only in local system I used to convert in JSON format.